# How to sort a linked list?

Tags: java, sorting, nullpointerexception, linked-list

I have tried it for the whole afternoon.
I even started to inspect my intelligence.
It's easy but I really dont know how to do.
please help me, thanks very very much!!!
implement linked list using java and sort it in alphabetical

[image]

```
public class SinglyLinkedList {
private static final int DEFAULT_MAXIMUM = 10;
private SLLNode[] listArray;
private int first = 0; // first element of the list in the array.
private int firstFree = 0; // first free location in the array.

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SinglyLinkedList elementList = new SinglyLinkedList();
    elementList.insert("Hydrogen");
    elementList.insert("Boron");
    elementList.insert("Beryllium");
    elementList.insert("Helium");
    elementList.insert("Lithium");
    elementList.insert("Carbons");

    System.out.println(elementList);
}

public SinglyLinkedList() {
    listArray = new SLLNode[DEFAULT_MAXIMUM];
}

public SinglyLinkedList(int size) {
    listArray = new SLLNode[size];
}

public void insert(String data) {
    inserts(data);
}

private void inserts(String data) {
    SLLNode tempNode = new SLLNode(data);
    listArray[firstFree] = tempNode;
    firstFree++;

    order();
}

private void order() {
    int i = 0;
    /*
     * for (i = 0; i < firstFree - 1; i++) { if(listArray[i].getNext()==-1) {
     * if(listArray[i].comparaTo(listArray[firstFree-1])<0)
     * listArray[firstFree-1].setNext(i); else { i++; if (listArray[firstFree -
     * 1].comparaTo(listArray[i]) > 0 && listArray[firstFree -
     * 1].comparaTo(listArray[listArray[i].getNext()]) < 0) {
     * listArray[i].setNext(firstFree - 1); listArray[firstFree -
     * 1].setNext(listArray[i].getNext()); } else listArray[firstFree -
     * 1].setNext(i); }
     * 
     * } else if (listArray[firstFree - 1].comparaTo(listArray[i]) > 0 &&
     * listArray[firstFree - 1].comparaTo(listArray[listArray[i].getNext()]) < 0) {
     * listArray[i].setNext(firstFree - 1); listArray[firstFree -
     * 1].setNext(listArray[i].getNext()); } else listArray[firstFree -
     * 1].setNext(i); }
     */
    for (i = 0; i < firstFree - 1; i++) {
        if (listArray[i].comparaTo(listArray[first]) < 0)
            first = i;
    }
    SLLNode tempNode = new SLLNode(listArray[first].getData());
    tempNode = listArray[first];
    /*
     * System.out.println("lala"); if(firstFree==1) listArray[first].setNext(0);
     * System.out.println("lala");
     */
    int j = 0;
    if(firstFree==1)
        tempNode.setNext(0);
    if(firstFree==2) {
        listArray[0].setNext(0);
        listArray[1].setNext(1);
    }
    while (tempNode.getNext()!=-1) {
        if (listArray[firstFree - 1].comparaTo(tempNode) > 0
                && listArray[firstFree - 1].comparaTo(listArray[tempNode.getNext()]) < 0) {
            listArray[firstFree - 1].setNext(tempNode.getNext() - 1);
            tempNode.setNext(firstFree-1);
        } else {
            tempNode = listArray[tempNode.getNext()];
        }

    }
    System.out.println("lala");
}

public String toString() {
    StringBuilder tempString = new StringBuilder();
    tempString.append("first = " + first + "\n" + "firstFree = " + firstFree + "\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < firstFree; i++) {
        if (listArray[i] != null)
            tempString.append(i + ": " + listArray[i].getData() + "\t" + listArray[i].getNext() + "\n");
    }
    return tempString.toString();
}

/*
 * public SLLIterator getIterator() {
 * 
 * }
 */

private static class SLLNode {
    private String data;
    private int next = -1;

    public SLLNode(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public SLLNode(String data, int next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return this.data;
    }

    public void setNext(int next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public int getNext() {
        return this.next;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "loading";
    }

    public int comparaTo(SLLNode tempNode) {
        if (data.compareTo(tempNode.getData()) > 0)
            return 1;
        else if (data.compareTo(tempNode.getData()) < 0)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}}
```

The main problem is the while loop and the nullPointerException
I dont know how to determine whether it's the end of the list

Comment: Why do you have the nodes of your linked list in an array?

Comment: Maybe you're making this difficult for yourself by trying to evolve the code from some array-based List implementation? A linked list is completely different.

Answer (score 1):

You need to break this into small parts:

1. Find the node after which your new node should go (let's call it `before`)
2. Find the existing node after that - it's `before.next` -- call it `after`. There might not be an `after`, in which case `before.next` will be `null`.
3. Make the new node's `next` point at `after`, or be `null`
4. Make `before.next` point at the new node

It's important that you understand what variables can be `null`, and what it means when they are:

- `firstNode` can be null. This means it's an empty list
- A node's `next` can be null. This means it's the last element in the list.

Your code must deal with both of these.

Take these one at a time. The first one is probably the most difficult, since the others are really simple.

A linked list doesn't store its elements in an array, and doesn't have a maximum size. The only field your `LinkedList` needs is `Node firstNode`. To reach the other elements you follow the `next` links from the first element. So:

```
 Node findInsertionPoint(String data) {
     Node node = this.firstNode;
     if(node == null) {
         return null;
     }
     Node nextNode = node.getNext();
     while(nextNode != null && nextNode.getData().compareWith(data) <=0) {
          node = nextNode;
          nextNode = node.getNext();
     }
     return node;
 }
```

This will return:

- `null` for an empty list (when `firstNode` is null)
- the `Node` *after which* your new node should go -- that is, the desired `before` in other cases.

`findInsertionPoint()` is a testable method in its own right, so test it and make sure it works for a number of cases, before moving on. An empty list. A single-element list. New node should go first. New node should go last. New node is in the middle.

Now you just need to create your new node, and call `setNext()` with the right value, on both the new node and the `before` node. If there is no `before` node, you need to instead set `this.firstNode` to point to the new node.

---

Note that you are not, here, sorting a linked list - you are inserting an element into the right position in an already-sorted list. One way to sort a linked list is to take its elements one-by-one and insert them into a new list in this way. But there are other more efficient ways, which you will probably encounter later in your studies.